# How can I query all records after a specific date?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, coding-style

This works in its current state but feels sloppy.

```
t = Time.local(2011, 8, 11)
comments_count = Comment.count(:conditions => ["comments.user_id = (?) AND comments.created_at > (?)" , record.user_id, t])
```

Can anybody suggest a different way I can write this query? I need to return a count of all the comments created after 08/11/2011.

EDIT: Rails 2.3.9

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.  Talking rails 2?  If in 3 you could pretty up the syntax a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clean the code up using named_scopes:

```
class Comment
  named_scope :for_user, lambda { |user_id|
    :conditions => ["comments.user_id = (?)", user_id]
  }
  named_scope :created_after, lambda { |time|
    :conditions => ["comments.created_at > (?)", time]
  }

  # ... rest of class ...
end
```

and then your query would be:

```
t = Time.local(2011, 8, 11)
comments_count = Comment.for_user(record.user_id).created_after(t).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a named scope for it:

```
named_scope :created_after, lambda {|time| { :conditions => ['created_at > ?', time] } }
named_scope :by_user, lambda {|user| { :conditions => ['user_id = ?', user.to_param] } }
```

then:

```
Comment.created_after(some_time).by_user(some_user)
```